# Are there any synonyms for "unimportant"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am an author and also a hypnotist.

In my native language, Danish, I can do magic with hypnosis, but it doesn't work so well in English.

If I want to stop an action, I can say in Danish "It is unimportant to smoke", and the person will stop smoking. But for some reason "unimportant" doesn't work so well in English.

Are there any other words meaning "unimportant" that I could use?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132824/discussion-on-question-by-author-jespersb-are-there-any-synonyms-for-unimportan).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "unnecessary". Or "You will no longer feel any need to smoke."

Comment: Many of the worthwhile things we do in life, such as contributing to this site, are unnecessary. Saying that something is unnecessary does not imply that we ought to abstain from it (which seems to be what the OP is trying to say).

Comment: Many things we do are unimportant (the word in the OP) so the above criticism doesn't seem particularly valid. Unnecessary sounds good for hypnosis but maybe in part because it sounds sophisticated and latinate.

Comment: @StuartF As an addiction, smoking can seem "necessary", smokers feel a compulsion to smoke, withdrawal from nicotine feels like not getting enough oxygen. In other words, absolutely necessary. "Unnecessary" is targeted at that feeling. As is "a need to smoke."

Answer (score 0):

For mere synonyms, you can always check https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unimportant

> Synonyms for unimportant
>
> fiddling, foolish, frivolous, incidental, inconsequential, inconsiderable, insignificant, little, Mickey Mouse, minor, minute, negligible, nugatory, slight, small, small-fry, trifling, trivial

or https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unimportant.

> SYNONYMS FOR unimportant
>
> frivolous,
> immaterial,
> inconsequential,
> insignificant,
> irrelevant,
> meaningless,
> negligible,
> null,
> trivial,
> unnecessary,
> useless,
> worthless,
> beside the point,
> casual,
> frothy,
> inconsiderable,
> indifferent,
> little,
> low-ranking,
> minor,
> minute,
> nonessential,
> nothing,
> nugatory,
> of no account,
> of no consequence,
> paltry,
> petty,
> picayune,
> second-rate,
> shoestring,
> slight,
> trifling,
> zero,
> zilch,
> zip

Although many of those words would imply that smoking is minute or negligible, (which is presumably not the intention), I would say that ***worthless***, ***useless***, and ***nonessential*** have the desired effect.

Comment: Hi, you can click the [edit] link under your answer to include the information from those sources so your answer might be more self-contained for when good links go bad.  Please see the [help] for more, and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question is at odds with its real content. The title seeks a synonym for *unimportant*, but the rest of the question reveals that the OP is really looking for a word that expresses a different concept. While there are plenty of synonyms and near-synonyms for *unimportant*, none of them will express this concept, because *unimportant* does not express it either.

Many of the things we do in life are not important, but we still do them, and think that doing them is perfectly OK. There is nothing wrong with doing unimportant things, as long as they don't get in the way of doing something more important. Contrary to what the OP assumes, saying that something is unimportant does not imply that it ought to be abstained from.

The concept of (un)importance is also ill-suited for what the OP has in mind because it cuts both ways: if something is unimportant, that weakens whatever reasons there may be for doing it, but also the reasons against doing it. An attempt to get others not to smoke usually manifests the belief that it is important whether people smoke or not.

If one needs to convey the idea that something ought not to be done, there is a short word that can do the job perfectly, so far as the language is concerned: ***bad***. Whether that word will, as a matter of human psychology, work in hypnosis, is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Somebody move my question and then change it. I can't use 'Not Important', because it doesn't work in the subconsciousness. The best one I think is pointless, but again I have to ask people when helping them.

Comment: Move your question where?

Comment: It was moved from 'Writing' to English.